# Need Help Converting AsyncTask to RxJava

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java

I dived into RxJava today.

I have an AsyncTask that Converts Image to Bitmap and sets it to Imageview.

I would like to convert it my AsyncTask to RxJava

This is my working AsyncTask below:

```
String imageurl = "http://example.com/image.jpg";

new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
            Bitmap theBitmap = null;
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                String TAG = "Message: ";

                try {
                    theBitmap = Glide.
                            with(mContext).
                            load(mValues.get(params[0]).
                            asBitmap().
                            into(-1, -1).
                            get();

                } catch (final ExecutionException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void dummy) {
                if (null != theBitmap) {
                    ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(theBitmap);
                }
            }
        }.execute(imageurl);
```

I know am suppose to provide codes I have tried, But I am having issues trying to wrap my head around RxJava. I just need something to start with.

I see this sample code , using Just where It passes Integers to the onNext() function.
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
          .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer item) {
            System.out.println("Next: " + item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("Sequence complete.");
        }
    });
```

Please, how can I convert this code, so I could use it like AsyncTask

Comment: you need to go a little further in the documentation to the part where it is explained how to create observables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```java
mSubscription = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Bitmap>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Bitmap> call() {
        return Observable.just(getBitmap(imageurl));
    }
})
        .filter(new Func1<Bitmap, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Bitmap bitmap) {
                return bitmap != null;
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {}

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Bitmap bitmap) {
                ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });

/* later in onDestroy(), onStop(), etc */
if (mSubscription != null && !mSubscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
    mSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Could you not use lambdas please...am not familiar with that yet, and how am I suppose to pass in my string as a parameter to the getBitmap() method ?

Comment: @HtmlTosin updated; `gitBitmap()` is just a place where you put your Glide-specific logic

Comment: Hi, It worked, But then I had to remove "mSubscription"  variable and just use it as `Observable.defer` ... It was saying "Cannot find symbol `mSubscription` ". Why that Though?

Comment: Because you didn't define this field in the class that uses this observable? I assumed the question wasn't about the basics of Java.

Comment: Ok, I guess you mean this - `Subscription mSubscription`

Comment: @TosinOnikute You really need to work on your basic java & lambda is not used at all. If it will be converted into lambda it will look like: 
                  Observable.subscribe(
                        (Bitmap bitmap)-> mSimpleStringAdapter.setStrings(colors),
                        (throwable) -> Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),
                        () -> {});